# how to implement code to displaying map point on the mapview after getting the location latitude and longiude?

Tags: iphone, ios4

hi all how to implement code for displaying the location point on the mapview after getting location latitude and longitude in the string format help me to solve the problem in iphone.

i mean i am getting location latitude and longitude in the string format but my intention is what i am getting latitude and longitude i have to show location point on the google map

i am getting location lati and longi in lattextfield.text=@"" and longtextfiels.text=@""
from -(void)getLoationdetails; method but how can we assign to mapview to display the map point on google mapview in iphone

can you provide the total code for applying lat and long sending to the mapview getting location point on the mapview in iphone

Comment: can u please tell us what is your approach towards this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.mapView.centerCoordinate = userLocation.location.coordinate;
            mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;
```

this should help.